# Mongodb and Symfony 5 - Command Requires Authentication

Tags: mongodb, symfony

I recently set up a project using Symfony 5 with the Doctrine MongoDB Bundle 4.3 (Doctrine ODM) and have been unable to insert documents through the ODM due to what appears to be an authentication error. When I attempt to do so I receive the error `Command Insert Requires Authentication`.

I have created a user for the database that the project will be using and assigned that user the dbAdmin role. According to the Symfony docs as well as the Doctrine ODM project docs, the correct way to pass credentials is in the `mongodb_server` parameter of the *services.yaml* config file. For example:

```
# config/services.yaml
parameters:
    mongodb_server: "mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/?authSource=auth-db"
```

I've verified that I've got the correct credentials, including the auth-db, and can successfully login in with these credentials via the Mongodb shell. I'm fairly confident that the username and password aren't being passed at all when trying to connect to the Mongo server and that I've likely missed some essential configuration setting, but can't see where that would be based on the Symfony documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed a configuration setting that has been missed here. In `config/packages/doctrine_mongodb.yaml` you have to add username, password and authSource connection options. Example:

```
# config/packages/doctrine_mongodb.yaml
doctrine_mongodb:
    # ...
    connections:
        default:
            server: "mongodb://localhost:27017"
            options:
                username: someuser
                password: somepass
                authSource: db_you_have_access_to
```

Unfortunately this can be tough to find in the Symfony docs, but it can be found in the [Doctrine MongoDB Bundle](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-bundle/en/4.3/config.html#using-authentication-on-a-database-level) documentation.